# Deserialize with RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, xml, restsharp

I've been looking on similar StackOverFlow posts but nothing seems to work.

I'm trying to deserialize an XML string that is being sent to me from a restful service using RestSharper. Basically, my problem is that some of the properties of my model class are being left null, and I have no clue why.

The model class I'm using is this:

```
class Photo
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "id")]
    public long? id { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "size")]
    public long? size { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "user")]
    public User user { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "tags")]
    public List<Tag> listTags { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "comments")]
    public List<Comment> listComments { get; set; }
}

class Photos
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "photos")]
    public List<Photo> listPhotos { get; set; }
}
```

The XML I'm trying to deserialize follows this structure :

```
    <photos>
      <photo>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>some title...</title>
        <description>some description...</description>
        <size>162798</size>
        <user>
           <id>4</id>
           <name>John</name>
       </user>
       <tags>
            <tag>
               <id>1</id>
               <value>some value...</value>
            </tag>
       </tags>
       <comments>
            <comment>
                <id>1</id>
                <value>some comment</value>
                <author>admin</author>
            </comment>
      </comments>
    </photo>
 </photos>
```

Back to the C# code. The thing is that the list of comments, the list of tags, and the user object of the Photo class are being left null . Does anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: just out of curiosity are your comment and tag class set to be serializeable?

Comment: yes they are set to be serializeable

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue, I went to the extent of recreating all the classes and xml, but it all came back without a problem. From the looks of it only the primitive types are being populated. Would you be able to publish a sample of the actual xml?

Comment: The xml is basically the same that I already posted. May I ask how are you doing the request to the restful service?? At the moment I'm using this to make the request: var client = new     RestClient(@"restfulpath");
            var request = new RestRequest("resourse", Method.GET);
            private Photos photos = new Photos();
            request.AddObject(photos);
            
            RestResponse<Photos> response =           (RestResponse<Photos>)client.Execute<Photos>(request);

Comment: I'm not making a call to the restful service, maybe that's where my disconnect is. I was approaching the issue from the standpoint that you already received the xml and you are trying to deserialize it back into a photos object, am I mistaken? Will restsharper allow you to just view the xml string as it came back? Just to verify the objects are there.

Comment: Yes. I tried printing the raw string on the client side and everything is there.

Comment: What happens when you take that string and try deserializing the code manually yourself?

Comment: I'm just learning to use RestSharper. What do you by deserializing the code manually? Could you provide any example

Comment: Sorry for the troubles. Managed to solve it. Just noticed a couple of the models on the client were missing the serializable annotation. Also some properties didn't match the xml nodes.

Comment: no troubles, my thoughts were leaning toward that in the beginning, glad you were able to figure it out.